# Extracting strings from source files during webpack bundling

Tags: vue.js, webpack, translation

I have a Vue application which uses Webpack 3 as bundler. The application contains custom translation tags (`{% trans %}...{% endtrans %}` as the templates used to be Jinja2 style) which get converted to `$(...)` as part of the bundling (using replace-string-loader), which `vuex-i18n` requires.

Is there a way to extract all `$t()` strings as part of the bundling into a file, so that this file can be translated? Since the replace-string-loader needs to process the files first, I expect this translation extractor to be integrated in the `webpack.conf` file (as part of the `module.rules` array)? Is there anything already out there which does the job or can someone please provide some help on how to write such a "loader"?

Answer (score 0):

if `$t()` is an invocation of a function, u can write a webpack plugin that will hook [the parser](https://webpack.js.org/api/parser/) and trace all of the invocations, then write them to file using [emit hook](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/#emit) to write the collected data to file.

```
compiler.hooks.normalModuleFactory.tap('MyPlugin', factory => {
  factory.hooks.parser.for('javascript/auto').tap('MyPlugin', (parser, options) => {
    parser.hooks.expression.for('$t').tap("MyPlugin", expr => {
       console.log(expr);
    });
  });
});
```

Good blog post about starting with webpack plugins: https://medium.com/webpack/the-contributors-guide-to-webpack-part-2-9fd5e658e08c

You can check the source code of [providePlugin](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/ProvidePlugin.js) as a reference, [read here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) what it does.